# How do I point 2 WAN IP address to the same machine?

Tags: networking

I've only experience in pointing a domain name to an IP address,

but never knows how do I point WAN IP address to a specific machine?

You can talk about it in either windows or linux,that's fine.

Comment: please explain your questions better. More information is required so we may help answer your Q.

Answer (score 1):

1. Call your ISP
2. Tell them you an additional IP address on your connection
3. ???
4. Profit

Answer (score 0):

Not clear from your question, but i think what you want is called multihoming.

its trivial in linux.  never tried it in windows, but it cant be that difficult.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multihoming

Linux (from the wiki article):
http://tetro.net/misc/multilink.html

Windows (again, from the wiki article):
http://web.archive.org/web/20070204050951/http://www.uit.co.uk/practical-tcpip/w-ipaliasw.pdf

Comment: Yes it's close,but it has to do with the ISP,right?Say,we as end users can't assign any IP to ourselves without authorization.

Comment: no, generally you cant just assign yourself an IP.  if youre getting into multipath routing to an ISP, thats exponentially more difficult than multihoming.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if I understand you correctly, the simple way to do this is NAT.  You just give the machine a private IP, and then on your router you NAT the specific WAN ip (and maybe port) to the internal IP.